How to debug an aws lambda function that is been invoked locally? Serverlessframework, NodeJS runtime, Windows10
I’m trying to setup a debugger when I run a function locally. Currently I execute function this way:
serverless invoke local --function myFunctionName --env dev --path ./events/myFunctionName.json

I’d like to know how could I debug this running function. I’m using Windows 10,NodeJS and ServerlessFramework v4.
Also I need suggestions in how to configure properly a debugger in VSCODE (or chrome) to debug properly using the tools mentioned before.
For example, using sam is as simple as:
sam local invoke myFunctionName--event ./events/myFunctionName.json --debug-port 9229

I'm not using sam though.

There is a way to use serverless on your local machine. you have to use a node package named serverless-offline. but to use that you have to initialize a serverless project and mention this plugin in serverless.yml file
After initializing the serverless project, you have to install serverless-offline using command npm i -D serverless-offline and then add this plugin inside serverless.yml file under plugins like this
plugins: 
  - serverless-offline

After that you have to start the serverless with serverless offline command. This will start the server on your local machine
If you want to debug a serverless function in vsCode you have to create launch.json file from run and dubug section in vscode. Add launch configuration like this
{
    "command": "npm start",
    "name": "Run npm start",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "node-terminal"
  }

Also add script in package.json file. After that run this launch file from vscode debug section and add breakpoint in vscode to debug your running functions

I'm invoking the function locally in my machine with serverless invoke local. I don't know why should I use a similar tool. Besides, you are not telling me how to debug a lambda using serverless-offline.

Ok i wiil update the answer accordingly
